# What is the song playing when Kallen is driving towards the convoy holding Suzaku?

Tags: music, code-geass

I've looked everywhere for it for ages, and I can't find it. What's the song in episode 4 of Code Geass (first season) at 12:50, beginning when Kallen is driving towards the convoy? It also plays at 4:35 of episode 11 (also the first season), beginning when Todo speaks to his subordinates.

Comment: Hey, I removed the links from your post, as it was not a legal provider. [how can I tell if a site is legal](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/1458)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was fine to use any site for reference. Thanks for the notice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The song you are looking for is called [Outside Road Code Geass](https://soundcloud.com/canis-lycaon/code-geass-r1-08-outside-road). It's the *Eight Song* in their soundtrack [Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/CDs).